# using a String[] outside a method

Tags: android, methods, scope

I am trying to use the `String[] mtake` outside the `onPostExecute(String)` method. It            gives me proper value inside the function but nothing in `onCreate()` method and simple crashes the app. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. I have tried declaring it public static globally and inside the class. Static doesn't work either.

```
@SuppressLint({ "CutPasteId", "SimpleDateFormat", "SdCardPath" }) 
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public String[] mtake;

    public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response.toString();
        }

        public void onPostExecute (String result) {
            mtake = result.split("#");
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Handler handIn = new Handler(); 
        final Timer T2 = new Timer(); 
        T2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { 
            public void run() { 
                handIn.post(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() {
                        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
                        txt.setText(mtake[0]);
                    }
                });
            }
        },0, 20000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't instantiating the `mTake` array with anything. In your `onPostExecute` method, you're calling `mTake.equals(result.split("#"))` which returns a `boolean`, not a String[]. Did you mean `mTake = result.split("#")`?

Comment: yes. it is actually that. Sorry, i didn't edit it... i will now

Comment: but doesn't solve the problem. mTake still behaves as a local String[] variable and i can not access it outside the onPostExecute() method